# Name of Lie algebras satisfying $[V,A]=sA$

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $A$ and $V$ are the generators of some Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. Furthermore, the $V$'s generate a subalgebra $\mathfrak v$ of $\mathfrak g$.

The $A$'s and $V$'s commute as follows:

$$
[V,A]=sA
$$

for some matrix $s$. This property is convenient, because then the exponentiated Lie group elements braid nicely:

$$
e^{V}e^{A} = e^{(e^{s})A}e^{V}.
$$

Does the subalgebra $\mathfrak v$ has any special name due to the above property?

---

As an example, say $V_i$ and $A_i$ (with $i=1,2,3$) are the six generators of $\mathfrak{so}$(4); furthermore, $V_i$ are the generators of the subalgebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Then it just happens to be the case that:

$$
[V_i,A_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}A_k.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "the $V$'s"?  There are more than one $V$?  There are also more than one $A$?  And why can a matrix $s$ operate on $A$?  Do you assume that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie subalgebra of some $\mathfrak{gl}(W)$, where $W$ is a vector space?  Or do you mean that $s$ is just a linear map from $\mathfrak{g}$ to itself?  Does $s$ depend on $A$ and $V$?

Comment: Maybe some examples will help clarify your question a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about special names... why do you need them? You are describing the standard [current algebras of QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_algebra). 
The *V*s are in the subalgebra and the *A*s are in the coset space.

In your particular example, the *V*s are the rotation group generators, so the "name" one describes the axials *A* with is "they transform as a vector of the rotation group". Your group composition braiding identity is merely the adjoint action of rotations on axial-generated group elements, Ad<sub>R</sub> exp(*A*).

If you endow a grading (+) on the *V*s in the subalgebra and (-) on the  *A*s, then you get the reminder from the 3 types of commutation relations in the algebra that that is graded, that is, the gradings (parity in physics) of the left- and right-hand sides match, upon multiplicative composition of the individual gradings.

Comment: Well, I guess current algebra is a good a name as any. Thanks.